# How to permanently edit httpd.conf for changes in apache 2.4 to take place even after app deployment?

Tags: httpd.conf, apache2.4

### **Apache 2.4**

I have added two lines the following two lines in the */etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf* file -

`Include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf`

`LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so`

Apache starts without errors. But, when I deploy my application on the beanstalk then it throws an error saying:

`Configuration error: No MPM loaded. [FAILED] Failed to execute 'service httpd start' Failed to execute 'service httpd start'`

New to this, please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @stolen_leaves Thanks for properly formatting my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to found a solution for this, forgot to answer.

In the `.ebextensions` folder of the project directory, edit the existing `httpd.conf` or create a new conf file and add the required changes here.

This will overwrite the default `httpd conf from httpd24` and our changes will reflect permanently. Deploy the application on elasticbeanstalk and we are good to go.

Hope this helps!!